# Javascript string search double and single quote using RegExp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, regexp-substr

I'm using the following code to search sub string in a string

```
mystring.search(new RegExp(substring, 'i'))
```

Reason why I am using `new RegExp` is, I want to search case insensitive. However, when there is a string like

`var mystring = '10" stick';`

and I want to search `10"`, the code above does not return any result. It's clearly because of `new RegExp` and double quote. Is there any particular flag that needs to be passed in `new RegExp`? I googled a lot but couldn't find any solution. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) returns match position, maybe ur confused by this. 
So, try this out,

```js
const myString = '10" stick';

console.log(myString.match(new RegExp('10"', 'i'))[0])
console.log(myString.match(new RegExp('ick', 'i'))[0])
console.log(myString.match(new RegExp('asd"', 'i'))) // non-matching
```

It returns the match or `null` if theres non. AND it matches `10"` in `10" stick`

see [`String.prototype.search` mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)